# set values ​for job variables from another file

Tags: slurm

I wanted to indicate the name and other values ​​of some variables of a job from another file but I get an error. 
`sbatch: error: Unable to open file 10:12:35`

**file.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
name='test__'$DATE
sbatch -J $name -o $name'.out' -e $name'.err' job.sh
```

**job.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --nodes=1                # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2      # number of cores
#SBATCH --output=.out
#SBATCH --error=.err

#module load R
Rscript script.R
```

**script.R**

```
for(i in 1:1e6){print(i)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly quoting the variables and the space requested in the date is creating two arguments to sbatch, hence he is complaining about that wrong parameter.

If I were you, I would avoid the space (as a general rule, cause it is more error prone and always requires quoting):

**file.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
name="test__$DATE"
sbatch -J "$name" -o "${name}.out" -e "${name}.err" job.sh
```